# Check existence of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I know how to check within a dictionary if a key or value is present.
IF you have a NESTED dictionary, before I add another dictionary to the outer one, is there a way to check if it already exists?
I.e if the Outer dictionary A, contains nested dictionaries B, C before I add another dictionary D to the outer A, how can I check if a dictionary with the name D already exists in A?  TIA

Comment: While the question's a little wonky, you may want to look at default dicts. 
If you're 'looking before you leap" and only calling `update` when a dict exists, defaultdict may fix your wagon.

Comment: `dict` don't have names.  Are you asking whether the same object (i.e. `id` matches) exists or object with the same values exist?

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan Scholbach said it better below I am trying to "Check that parent has no sub-dict with same name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear. I try to cover all possible scenarios I can think of:

## Check that candidate is not contained in parent

You can check if a given dict is in the values of the parent dict by using the `values()` method of the parent dict. Be aware that this does not check for the order of the keys, because a dictionary's keys just do not have a particular (fixed, or "frozen") order, and two dictionaries are considered equal no matter of the order of their keys:

```
parent = {
   "b": {
        "hey": "ho",
        "let's": "go"
   },
   "c": {"another": "value"}
}

candidate = {
    "let's": "go",
    "hey": "ho"
}
```

Then:

```
>>> candidate in parent.values()
True
```

So, if I understand your question right, you get what you want by:

```
if candidate not in parent.values():
    parent["candidate"] = candidate
```

## Check that parent has no sub-dict with same "name"

However, if you actually do not want to check whether the given dictionary is in the parent dictionary, but just want to check whether there is a nested dictionary inside the parent dictionary with the same *name* as the candidate dictionary, just look for the `items()` of the parent dict:

```
if not "candidate" in parent:  # this is equal to 
# if not "candidate" in parent.items():
    parent["candidate"] = candidate
```

## Check that parent has no sub-dict with same "name" or content

And, finally, if you want to check both conditions, i.e. you want to check whether there is a nested dict inside the parent dict with equal content or equal name as the given candidate dict, just combine both conditions:

```
if not "candidate" in parent and not candidate in parent.values():
    parent["candidate"] = candidate
```

Comment: Thank you,  I tried to frame the question clearly, but as you described I am trying to "Check that parent has no sub-dict with same name".